# Sharing DB entity context between refresh token provider and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I currently have a refresh token system (implementing `IAuthenticationTokenProvider`) set up in the fairly standard OWIN fashion in my Web API server.

This gets assigned in the `ConfigureAuth()` method of `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```cs
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(accessTokenValidity),
    Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
});
```

I then have various controllers (extending `ApiController`) that manage their own DB (Entity Framework) contexts, but access/refresh tokens being processed through the token provider use the DB context within the provider itself.

I want to invalidate a refresh token in the DB outside the normal flow, via an endpoint within one of the above controllers. The problem with doing this is that as the context isn't shared, it causes optimistic concurrency exceptions the next time a token DB action is carried out.

What's the best way for me to be able to share (or access) a context to avoid these exceptions?

Making the context static and accessing it via **static methods** within the provider feels wrong, but would probably solve the problem. Edit: And there's no thread safety, so there goes that option.

I can **pass something into a constructor** for the provider, but I don't immediately see a way to then share that with the controllers.

Another option is continually **forcing an entity refresh**, but that feels hacky and still potentially could have concurrency problems.

Edit: A fourth option is to create a new `DbContext` every time I need to perform operations, be it in the provider or in the controller. This appears to be MS's recommendation, and may in fact be my chosen solution. However, I feel like this still potentially leaves the door open for concurrency issues if two requests modify a record simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest to use DI container like Unity or Autofac, 
you could register the dbcontext as SingleInstancePerRequest,and inject the dbcontext in the constructors,